# when I run the jar file in command prompt i am getting error?

Tags: java, zebra-printers, zpl

I have included zebra SDK external lib in my project it is inside lib folder in my project.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>your.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>external-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2275</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}${file.separator}lib${file.separator}ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

---

```java
private boolean checkPrinterStatus(String ipAddress, int portNumber) {
    try {
        Connection connection = new TcpConnection(ipAddress, portNumber);
        connection.open();
        ZebraPrinter printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(connection);
        PrinterStatus printerStatus = printer.getCurrentStatus();
        return printerStatus.isReadyToPrint && !printerStatus.isPaused;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I compile it is working fine, when I maven clean and install it generates JAR file without any problem.

When I run the JAR file in command prompt
the below error I am getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.launch(ThinJarWrapper.java:139)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.main(ThinJarWrapper.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot build model
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.DependencyResolver.dependencies(DependencyResolver.java:254)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.PathResolver.extract(PathResolver.java:265)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.PathResolver.resolve(PathResolver.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ThinJarLauncher.java:393)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ThinJarLauncher.java:376)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.getClassPathArchivesIterator(ThinJarLauncher.java:226)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:55)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.launch(ThinJarLauncher.java:221)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.main(ThinJarLauncher.java:168)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: hidden.org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for your.groupId:external-library:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 78, column 25[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for your.groupId:external-library:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${basedir}/lib/ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar @ line 78, column 25

        at hidden.org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:192)
        at hidden.org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:123)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.DependencyResolver.dependencies(DependencyResolver.java:213)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: hidden.org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException: 2 problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example:Atlas_Printer_Project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for your.groupId:external-library:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 78, column 25[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for your.groupId:external-library:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${basedir}/lib/ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar @ line 78, column 25

        at hidden.org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProblemCollector.newModelBuildingException(DefaultModelProblemCollector.java:197)
        at hidden.org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:482)
        at hidden.org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:424)
        at hidden.org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:414)
        at hidden.org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:158)
        ... 14 more
```

Comment: It's not a direct duplicate, but this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65609238/2846138) could solve your problem: don't use system scope.

Comment: You can use `mvn install:install-file` to make sure you can add it just like any other dependency